# What does `Kbytes RSS Dirty` mean for pmap?

Tags: linux, memory-usage

output of `pmap`:

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
00000000006b4000      60      16      16 rw---    [ anon ]
```

What's it saying ?

Answer (score 7):

From man:

- Address:  start address of map
- Kbytes:   size of map in kilobytes
- RSS:  resident set size in kilobytes
- Dirty:    dirty pages (both shared and private) in kilobytes
- Mode: permissions on map: read, write, execute, shared, private (copy on write)
- Mapping:  file backing the map, or '[ anon ]' for allocated memory, or '[ stack ]' for the program stack

Answer (score 4):

Here pamp specifics ...
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-find-memory-used-by-program.html

http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/pmap/

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118307/a-way-to-determine-a-processs-real-memory-usage-i-e-private-dirty-rss It explains what RSS and Dirty seems to be ...

Comment: -1 The question asks about the meaning of particular fields. The answer provides generic links about pmap usage.